# How to debug modsecurity_audit_log

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-security

I was accessing `www.example.com/RestAPI/index.php/tweets.json` in my server.

The `modsec_audit.log` showed the following error, but there is no related errors/warnings in `modsec_debug.log`. I could see the Internal Server error is logged in example-error_log.

How can I debug this Internal Server error?

> --8560e90b-A--
>
> [21/Mar/2012:07:01:52 +0000] T2l84H8AAAEAAGxPZ@QAAAAG x.x.x.x 33101 x.x.x.x 80
>
> --8560e90b-B--
>
> GET /RestAPI/index.php/tweets.json HTTP/1.1
>   Host: www.example.com
>   User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:11.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/11.0
>   Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
>   Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
>   Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
>   DNT: 1
>   Cookie: __utma=159129855.1463065063.1331789485.1331789485.1331789485.1; __utmz=159129855.1331789485.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); 8cb6a414cf5ec1919864de0e80bea4da=0es7dcu0p10cocfpferb2lddi0; 8926e4f3c475bb6fcacb409299f1bd27=53cf8c5e6bf78ea45096945377e6d609
>   Connection: keep-alive
>   Cache-Control: max-age=0
>
> --8560e90b-F--
>
> HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error
>   X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.5
>   Content-Length: 0
>   Connection: close
>   Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
>
> --8560e90b-H--
>
> Apache-Handler: php5-script
>   Stopwatch: 1332313312358005 130428 (- - -)
>   Producer: ModSecurity for Apache/2.5.12 (http://www.modsecurity.org/); core ruleset/2.0.5.
>   Server: Apache
>
> --8560e90b-Z--

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess mod_security is really just a messenger here, and not blocking anything by itself. HTTP 500 Internal Server Error is typically caused by

- A faulty Apache configuration for that virtual host / directory
- A faulty .htaccess file in that directory
- Something else

Does everything else work fine at your server and only the tweets.json does not?

Comment: You are correct, Janne. I've disabled modsecurity and still gets 500 error.

Comment: Everything else in the server works fine.
The  tweets.json file's directory was recursively copied from another path ( and from that path tweets.json is working fine ) in the same virtualhost . The htaccess file is also looks good.

Can there be any other reasons?